# Downgrade Gradel Buildship to 2.x from 3.x

Tags: eclipse, gradle, eclipse-plugin, spring-tool-suite, gradle-plugin

Currently I have Buildship 3.x in STS I want downgrade it to 2.x. When I try to create project I am getting error like this

```
Can not import using Gradle (Buildship 2.x) because Buildship Gradle Tooling version 2.x is not installed. You can install it from Eclipse Marketplace.
```

When I check in marketplace showing only 3.x not 2.x.After uninstalling 3.x I tried to install 2.x from marketplace but showing only 3.x

Comment: Can you give an example of how to reproduce the root issue, the error message saying Buildship 2.x is required? Instead of looking for a way to downgrade, try to fix the root cause (maybe the other software used is too old or somewhere a version range is declared too restrective). [Eclipse 2018-09 contains Buildship 2.2.1](https://projects.eclipse.org/releases/2018-09), but that is five releases behind.

Comment: @howlger I am using sts 3.9.3.While creating spring starter project there is option to select type buildship(1.x or 2.x or maven project).From market space I updated build ship to 3.0.Now when I try to create project in type option buildship 3.x is not showing.So I selected 2.x  to proceed getting error like this  Can not import using Gradle (Buildship 2.x) because Buildship Gradle Tooling version 2.x is not installed. You can install it from Eclipse Marketplace.

Comment: Please edit your question so that someone else can reproduce the issue, starting with the exact steps you used to create the new project.